# How do I return identical values between two string aggregated columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-aggregation, string-agg

I have 2 columns A & B in a SQL Server table that contain a string aggregated list of codes.

The codes in the lists are separated by a semicolon.

The string aggregated lists can take any length and the codes can be in any order.

What I would like to do is to create a new column C which contains the codes that appear somewhere in the same row of the lists of Column A and Column B.

Example:

| Column_A | Column_B | Column_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a;b;c;d;e | c;a;e;i;k | c;a;e |
| d;e;f;g | e;h;i;j;d | e;d |

The example above returns "c", "a" and "e" for the first row of column C, because these codes are present in the same row of both Column A and Column B.

The same for the second row, here "e" and "d" are overlapping in Column A and B and thus returned in Column C.

I have tried something that works, but it does not seem like the best solution in terms of efficiency and performance. Especially because I have many (1m+) rows to check this for and the length of code lists to compare can be very long.

```
SELECT 
    STRING_AGG(CAST([value] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),'; ') AS Overlapping_Code 
FROM
    (SELECT a.value 
     FROM MyTable t 
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t.Column_A, ';') a

     INTERSECT

     SELECT b.value 
     FROM MyTable t 
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t.Column_B, ';') b 
) ab
```

I am looking for a better solution in terms of performance and elegance to compare the string aggregated lists for two columns across (many) rows.

Comment: Why are you storing your data in a denormalised format would be my question. Why not use a normalised design? Then getting values in one set that appear in another is trivial. *"I have tried something that works, but it does not seem like the best solution in terms of efficiency and performance. "* That, likely, is more the fault of your design than anything.

Comment: The table that I am working with is a temporary table which is a result of a long query. I had many rows before aggregation, each row containing one code. I thought it might be easier to flatten the data to one row with all codes combined in one string and then compare row by row if the codes are returning somewhere. I am not sure I understand you, can you give an example of what a normalised design would look like?

Comment: A normalised design would have 3 tables, 1 with all the value for `A`, another with all the values for `B` (both with respective IDs) and then a 3rd with the IDs that are linked.

Comment: Something like this perhaps: SELECT column_a, column_b, string_agg(value, ';') within GROUP(ORDER BY value)
FROM (
 SELECT column_a, column_b, y.value
 FROM
 (
  VALUES (N'a;b;c;d;e', N'c;a;e;i;k', N'c;a;e')
  , (N'd;e;f;g', N'e;h;i;j;d', N'e;d')
 ) t (Column_A,Column_B,Column_C)
 CROSS apply string_split(column_a + ';' + column_b, ';') y
 GROUP BY y.value, column_a, column_b
 HAVING count(*) > 1
 ) x
GROUP BY column_a, column_b

Comment: as thom wrote though, you should avoid *storing* csv in sql

Comment: @Yosh07 your table contains two string columns, not two columns with values. It doesn't matter how developers or business users interpret them, those are just strings. If you want to treat these as values you'll have to use `STRING_SPLIT` to convert them to individual values and maybe calculate their OUTER JOIN.

Comment: @Yosh07 what was the original query and why do you think squashing the data would help? Especially when you still need access to individual values? It's probably easier to do what you want using better tables and scripts. The schema for a transactional database can be very different from the schema of a *reporting* database

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The original query returned the rows seperately, so "a" on the first row, "b" on the second, etc. Moreover, Column B did not exist, this is a LEAD of Column A, so the next session where codes may occur. Column B = Column A + 1 so to say. I think I will return to the design stage to see if I can make it easier for myself earlier in the query.

Comment: Are all your codes 1 character in length?

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: @ThomA No the examples are simplified, code lengths range between 5-10 characters

Comment: @Yosh07 you keep describing an abstract of your attempted solution, not the problem. What are the actual table? Products? Sales? Are you trying to match items by flags? What's the actual *business* problem? Right now the examples are so simplified they're meaningless

Comment: SSMS is an administration tool, not a database. It can connect to almost all SQL Server versions going back to 2005

Comment: SSMS version is irrelevant. We need SQL Server version. Please issue `SELECT @@VERSION;`, and share the output.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos SQL Server 2019, sorry SQL noob here

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the business problem is that matching codes between 2 sessions mean that the errors are returning in the next session. I want to pinpoint to those sessions where errors are not resolved. Column A would be session 1, where the same row in Column B would be session 2. It used to be a long list of sessions with an even longer list of codes per session. I thought it would make it easier to split the sessions to two columns to have a side-by-side comparison. Also to concatenate the error codes to flatten the data to 1 row. I guess I didn't make it easier this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another possible solution:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (a VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, b VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL /* PRIMARY KEY ?? */);

INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ('a;b;c;d;e','c;a;e;i;k'),('d;e;f;g','e;h;i;j;d');

SELECT *,
    (SELECT STRING_AGG(x.value,';')
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(a,';') AS x
    , STRING_SPLIT(b,';') AS z
    WHERE x.value=z.value)
FROM mytable AS t;



a          b          c          
---------- ---------- -------
a;b;c;d;e  c;a;e;i;k  c;a;e
d;e;f;g    e;h;i;j;d  e;d
```

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to split your strings, check if the value is in the other column's dataset and then reaggregate. This differs from your attempt as this doesn't reference the same table twice, just once. This isn't ideal and the order will be arbitrary, as you are on SQL Server 2019 (not 2022):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES('a;b;c;d;e','c;a;e;i;k','c;a;e'),
            ('d;e;f;g','e;h;i;j;d','e;d'))V(A,B,C)
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT STRING_AGG(BB.value,';') AS C
                  FROM STRING_SPLIT(V.B,';') BB
                  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                FROM STRING_SPLIT(V.a,';') AA
                                WHERE BB.value = AA.value))E;
```

Ideally, as I mentioned, you should be treating your data in a normalised form. I normalise your data using the sample you've given us, and then you can use an `EXISTS` to get the values that are in both sets:

```sql
SELECT *
INTO #YourBadData
FROM (VALUES(1,'a;b;c;d;e','c;a;e;i;k','c;a;e'),
            (2,'d;e;f;g','e;h;i;j;d','e;d'))V(ID,A,B,C);
GO
--Create normalised tables
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableA (ID int, Code char(1));
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableB (ID int, Code char(1));
CREATE TABLE dbo.RelatedIDs (A int, B int);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.TableA (ID, Code)
SELECT YBD.ID,
       SS.Value
FROM #YourBadData YBD
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(YBD.A,';') SS;
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.TableB (ID, Code)
SELECT YBD.ID,
       SS.Value
FROM #YourBadData YBD
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(YBD.B,';') SS;

GO
INSERT INTO dbo.RelatedIDs (A,B) --This is overly simplified, as I assume A and B would likely
                                 --have different IDs and come from different sources
SELECT ID, ID
FROM dbo.#YourBadData; 
GO

SELECT B.ID,
       B.Code
FROM dbo.TableB B
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.RelatedIDs RI
                   JOIN dbo.TableA A ON RI.A = A.ID
              WHERE RI.B = B.ID
                AND A.Code = B.Code);


GO
--Clean up
DROP TABLE #YourBadData;
DROP TABLE dbo.TableA;
DROP TABLE dbo.TableB;
DROP TABLE RelatedIDs
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dR3fbsIh)

Comment: This confirms that I overcomplicated matters by doing a string aggregation of the codes in the first place. As your first step is actually bringing it back to my original data format. Thanks for taking the time to share.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution based on the set operator `INTERSECT`

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, colA VARCHAR(20), colB VARCHAR(20));
INSERT @tbl (colA, colB) VALUES
('a;b;c;d;e', 'c;a;e;i;k'),
('d;e;f;g', 'e;h;i;j;d');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t.*,
    (
        SELECT STRING_AGG(value, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value) AS common_codes
        FROM (
            SELECT value
            FROM STRING_SPLIT(ColA, ';')
            INTERSECT
            SELECT value
            FROM STRING_SPLIT(ColB, ';')
        ) AS common_codes
    ) AS ColC
FROM @tbl as t;
```

**Output**

| ID | colA | colB | ColC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a;b;c;d;e | c;a;e;i;k | a;c;e |
| 2 | d;e;f;g | e;h;i;j;d | d;e |

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `CHARINDEX` to check which characters are in A and B.

```
SELECT
    Column_A,
    Column_B,
    (
        SELECT
            STRING_AGG(code, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY code) AS common_codes
        FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT value AS code
            FROM STRING_SPLIT(Column_A, ';')
            WHERE CHARINDEX(';' + value + ';', ';' + Column_B + ';') > 0
        ) AS common_codes
    ) AS Column_C
FROM yourdata;
```